# Achilles heel snapped twice without permanent damage

Tags: running, injury

Yesterday i was faced with a strange "injury".
Last week i lightly strained my achilles heel when making a strange twist with my foot. after a week of complete rest the pain fully subsided.

Tuesday i went for a small/slow run. I still felt something odd in the achilles heel but no pain and I could keep on running. I ran 5.5 km (didn't want to overdo it).

Yesterday morning I still wasn't feeling anything so i decided to do a light run in the evening (9.5km). Which is not unusual for me (I normally run 40km+ in a week).  I started running and for the first 6k i did again feel that achilles heel with some very, very slight dull pain. At the 6k mark my achilles heel snapped twice (almost lost my balance) in 30 - 50m. At first a sharp pain but then again the pain disappeared.

At first i panicked. I stopped on the side of the road to see what was wrong. The achilles heel could still support my weight.So I walked some meters but then i was able to run the remaining 3k to home. Constantly feeling a light dull, non-hampering (my tempo didn't suffer) pain.

At home there wens't any redness or inflammation visibile. To be sure I iced it, still feeling the light pain. This morning I awoke with the same light pain.But by now (10 AM) the pain is again gone.

The problem obviously isn't a tear or a rupture in/of the tendon. Any significant injury would have prevented me from continuing the run. Nor can i find any information about the snap (without rupture) on the net.

What happened to tendon to snap like that? Is there something i should worry about?

By snapping I mean the following:
It was just like a large amount of pressure suddenly got released by the heel. Like the heel couldn't handle the stress anymore and it give way in an instant, releasing all the stress in a single burst. This gave me the weird sensation of "falling" through my foot.

P.S. I have had no Achilles heel injuries prior to this one. Or any other injury in the last 4 months.

P.S. 2: I'm made an appointment with the doctor. But i would still like the input from some seasoned runners.

Comment: As a person born with too short achilles tendons and have had trouble due to it - do NOT take it lightly, it's one of the worst places to injure yourself so even though you might feel fine definitely get it checked before running again.

Comment: A person with a ruptured Achilles cannot stand on it and describe the pain as being shot and kicked extremely hard in that area. You can see if it has ruptured by laying on your stomach flat and trying to point your toes downwards (or just try to point your toes, you shouldn't be able to on affected foot). The affected ankle will have no tendon definition. You could have impingement or tendonitis or a simple tear but only a doctor can diagnose your problem.

Comment: @JJChivers I know that it isn't a rupture or a tear. Those injuries would prevent me from even walking decently. In fact I would expect that any injury to the heel (no matter how slight), would prevent the a normal running tempo. But i must say, the snapped-feeling was really terrifying and gave me an terrible akward feeling. I never felt anything like that before.

Comment: To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.” http://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "snapped"?

Comment: @SeanDuggan It really felt as though it snapped. Causing me to "lose control" for a second or so. I could best describe it as "falling through my foot with the loss of all control". It was just like there was a massive stress/pressure buildup which got released at single instance. I've edited the question

Comment: @JJChivers - Not necessarily true. I ruptured my achilles, and while it felt like I had gotten hit with something or stepped on (I was in martial arts class) when it happened, I was able to walk with a modified gait and little to no pain. You are correct in not being able to point your toes.

Comment: Got the doctors results yesterday. The earlier strain apparently (visible on the echo) caused a bleed in/around the achilles heel. This is has no effect during daily routines. But as you exercise, the achilles heel start to expand. which in turn (as it cannot expand normally) causes enormous pressure on the heel itself. The pressure builds up to a certain point where the heel suddenly shifts into another position. This caused the snap. The doctor said i was very lucky not to rupture the heel. But i ain't allowed to run for a month or two.